# Unit testing custom action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a custom action filter (attribute) that hits a database. How can I unit test the controller actions by injecting a mock repository (so that it doesn't actually hit the database for the unit test) for the action filter to use?

Comment: I'm thinking that I have a base controller with a property to the IRepository. The action filter can then get the controller from the context, cast it to the base controller type (assuming the cast succeeds) and get access to the IRepository. It can then use whatever Repository has been set on the controller which will be a mock one from a unit test.

Comment: Two things that concern me about this though

1) How can I ensure the custom filter is not applied to a controller that does not inherit from the base controller?

2) I just noticed that the custom action filter doesn't even get called from a unit test since I call the action directly as functions- eg. controller.Index(). How can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question a couple of weeks ago.

[How do I unit test an ActionFilter in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609942/unittest-actionfilter)

At the end I accepted that I have to test the controller without the filter and test the filter itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info but it does not explain how the action filter can work with a mock repository that I can inject from the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use StructureMap or some other service locator-ish pattern.